# Running Mail Merge on Embedded Document in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I am looking for code that will open all embedded documents within a Word document, update the mail merge info, and close the file again.

Here's the story: I have about twenty documents that contain instructions on how to get access to various systems. These documents are role-specific—meaning that depending on the user's needs, these instructions vary from document to document.

At the present, anytime a system changes their access procedures, I have to go into each of the twenty documents and update the necessary information. I have been working on a solution to improve the workflow but have hit a little snag.

I have created system-specific documents that contain the information to access the individual systems. I have then embedded these system-specific documents into the original role-specific documents. This has the desired effect—I am able to manipulate information in the system access document and it will update information in the documents for all the necessary roles.

That part isn't the snag. This is the snag. In each system access document, I have a mail merge running that puts in role specific data (i.e., login info, role, department, etc.) The mail merge collects information from a master user excel file.

The overall effect here would be that I can input user data into the user excel file, open the role-specific instructions needed for that user, and have all the embedded documents already run the updated mail merge info *without* having to open each system-specific document and updating the mail merge info.

I am looking for code that will open all embedded documents within a Word document, update the mail merge info (this generally occurs upon the file opening), and close the file again.

If anyone can help with this little scenario, or if anyone has a much more better idea that would work, please let me know.